# Drag & Drop Issues With Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, lightbox

I have a drag and drop function set up on a site I'm working on and I'm having a few issues.

1) When I release an object from a drag it triggers the Lightbox link, how can I block this function from occurring unless it's just a solid click.

2) In the code below where I define which elements can be dragged, the only workable class is '.photo', which on my site is an oversized box (for layout purposes), and isn't an acceptable option for my needs. The classes used for the images ('.img1' '.img2') don't seem to work and even if I build a .div around the images it won't work with that class either.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(function($){
$('.photo').drag(function( ev, dd ){
    $( this ).css({
        top: dd.offsetY,
        left: dd.offsetX
    });
 });
```

});

Any ideas on how to tackle these issues?

http://www.coreytegeler.com/jb/3/

Comment: Have you tried `ev.stopPropagation()`? http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: Nope! How could I add that into what I have?

Comment: Tried adding `event.stopPropagation();` into the function but I'm guessing that's not correct

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `event.stopPropagation()`?

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.photo').drag(function( event, dd ) {
        event.stopPropagation();

        $( this ).css({
            top: dd.offsetY,
            left: dd.offsetX
        });
    });
});
```

- More info about drag: [info](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag)
- More info about stopPropagation: [info](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: This breaks something and prevents any images from loading. even without the 'event.stopPropagation();' it doesn't work do to the 'event' in the function. I tried switching 'event' to 'ev' in both instances, it allows the images to show, but continues my original problem.

Comment: Also the lightbox doesn't pop up when I release the image in a place in which the bounding box is under another element.

Comment: Ok I now have the given code in place and everything else works, but I still have the initial issues

Comment: Just added a link to a demo page, thought it was up there but I guess not